# Determine whether or not each of the given vector fields is conservative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Determine whether or not each of the given vector fields is conservative.

If the vector field is conservative, find a potential function for the field.

(a) $\vec{F}\left(x, y\right) = \left(x^2 + y^2\right)\vec{i} - 2x\vec{j}$

(b) $\vec{F}\left(x, y\right) = \left(2x + y\cos \left(xy\right), x\cos \left(xy\right)-1\right)$

**my attempt**

(a) $P = x^2 + y^2$ and $Q = -2x$

$\frac{dP}{dy} = 2y$ and $\frac{dQ}{dx} = -2$

since $\frac{dP}{dy} ≠ \frac{dQ}{dx}$ F cannot be conservative

(b)

$P = 2x + y \cos \left(xy\right)$ and $Q = x\cos \left(xy\right) - 1$

$\frac{dP}{dy} = \cos \left(xy\right) - xy\sin \left(xy\right)$

$\frac{dQ}{dx} = \cos \left(xy\right) - xy\left(\sin \left(xy\right)\right)$

since they're equal $F$ has to be conservative

so let (1) (2) respectively : $\frac{df}{dx} = 2x + y \cos \left(xy\right), \frac{df}{dy} = x\cos \left(xy\right)-1$

integrate (1) with x

$f\left(x, y\right) = x^2 + \sin \left(xy\right) + g\left(y\right)$ (3)

diff with y

$\frac{df}{dy} = x\cos \left(xy\right) + g'\left(y\right)$

combine from (2)

$x\cos \left(xy\right) + g'\left(y\right) = x\cos \left(xy\right) - 1$

$g'\left(y\right) = -1$

integrate with y

$g\left(y\right) = -y$

from (3)

$f\left(x, y\right) = x^2 + \sin \left(xy\right) - y$ is a potential function

is this right?